# Percona 5.6 Docker Image cannot load my /etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, centos7, selinux

I am struggling on this issue for at least 14 hours so far :(.

I am configuring a build server with docker, jenkins, java, scala on top of CentOS 7.

While working with liquibase and jooq:codegen, I need to have proper MySQL(Percona:5.6) containers setup, but unfortunately, it seems that Official Percona Image (Percona:5.6) does not load *.cnf files under /etc/mysql/conf.d properly, which I do think it is my issue, such as file permissions issues.

I was following with the instructions from: [Docker Hub: Percona](https://hub.docker.com/_/percona/)
[image: Percona Official: Using a custom MySQL configuration file]
But it does not work for me, and I tried so many wrong ways, none was working.

The file/folders permissions are like following picture:
[image: *.cnf files inside conf.d folder from hosting server]

After mounted into container, they are as following picture:
[image: *.cnf files inside /etc/mysql/conf.d inside Container]

And the docker-compose.yaml is as following:
[image: docker-compose.yaml]

The default my.cnf provided by Official Percona 5.6 is as following:

```
root@25295730da09:/etc/mysql# cat my.cnf
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
#
# * Basic Settings
#
#user       = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
#log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#slow_query_log      = 1
#long_query_time = 2
#log_queries_not_using_indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

And my customization is as following:

```
root@25295730da09:/etc/mysql/conf.d# cat my.cnf
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
general_log             = 1

log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
max-connections = 5000

max_allowed_packet=32M

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 2048

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 256M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 128M


#server_id=1
#log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used (fedora >= 15).
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
user=mysql
lower_case_table_names=1
# Semisynchronous Replication
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html
# uncomment next line on MASTER
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_master=semisync_master.so
# uncomment next line on SLAVE
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_slave=semisync_slave.so

# Others options for Semisynchronous Replication
;rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled=1
;rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout=10
;rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled=1

# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html
;performance_schema

# Set default server character set

character-set-server = utf8

# Set default server collation

collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

And my docker versions:

```
[barry@eb-build linux-build-server]$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Wed Apr 27 00:34:42 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Wed Apr 27 00:34:42 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
[barry@eb-build linux-build-server]$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35
docker-py version: 1.8.1
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
[barry@eb-build linux-build-server]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason is because the directory:  /etc/mysql/conf.d should have at least 555 permission.

problems solved.