# mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: java, mysql, docker, kubernetes

docker-mysql-configmap.yml

````
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: mysql-initdb-config 
data: 
    initdb.sql:
        use mydb;
        create table product(
        id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar(20),
        description varchar(100),
        price decimal(8,3) 
        );
            
        create table coupon(
        id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        code varchar(20) UNIQUE,
        discount decimal(8,3),
        exp_date varchar(100) 
        ); ```

db-mysql-service.yml

```apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: docker-mysql
    labels:
        app: docker-mysql
spec:
    selector:
        app: docker-mysql
    
    ports:
        - port: 3306
          targetPort: 3306     
          nodePort: 30287  
    type: NodePort 

        
   ``` >


db-sql-deplymonent.yml

```apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
    name: docker-mysql
    labels:
        app: docker-mysql
spec:
    replicas: 1  
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: docker-mysql      
    template:
        metadata:
            labels: 
                app: docker-mysql
        spec:
          volumes: 
            - name: mysql-initdb-vol
              configMap:
                name: mysql-initdb-config 
          containers: 
                 - name: docker-mysql
                   image: mysql
                   volumeMounts:
                    - name:  mysql-initdb-vol
                      mountPath: /docker-entrypont-initdb.d
                   
                   
                   env:
                     - name: MYSQL_DATABASE 
                       value: mydb 
                     
                        
                     - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
                       value: norton09   
                     - name: MYSQL_ROOT_HOST
                       value: '%'
````

when i checking logs of pod i am getting errors.

2020-09-06 01:10:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-09-06 01:10:15+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
command was: mysqld --verbose --help
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what environment, kubernetes or mysql version are you using but there a few things which might help with this issue.

1. **Change access to this file/directory**
   You also didnt mention if you want to check how it works or it will be used in production. If this solution would fit your needs you could change permissions to the file using `chown` command.

Additional information can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501725/percona-5-6-docker-image-cannot-load-my-etc-mysql-conf-d-cnf) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066411/mysql-error-error-1018-hy000-cant-read-dir-of-errno-13).

2. **Disabling apparmor**

As mentioned in [this Github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7906) you can disable apparmor for `mysql` or use command form [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7512#issuecomment-61787845). You can also check [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091803/unable-to-install-mysql-with-cant-read-dir-of-etc-mysql-conf-d-error) for more information.

3. **Use `privilaged` option**

It was cover by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768828/gitlab-runner-mysqld-cant-read-dir-of-etc-mysql-conf-d)

You could also check [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958575/docker-mysqld-cant-read-dir-of-etc-mysql-mysql-conf-d-os-errno-2-no-suc) if you are using `docker-compose`.

Please let me know if any of those options worked for you or you still have issue.